# How do I change the background color of a textblock in MVVM-WPF

Tags: textblock

I am new to WPF technology. i am using MVVM architecture.
I want to change the background of textblock based on viewmodel's attribute.
e.g If i am using 'brush' object, I want to bind it to background color of textblock.

```
<TextBlock Margin="0,1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Arial"
                    FontSize="16"
                    Text="{Binding Line}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Background="{Binding brushobj}"/>
```

How to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define it like this, inside your ViewModel.

```
private Brush _brushobj;
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the BrushObject.
/// </summary>
public Brush BrushObj
{
    get
    {
        return _brushobj;
    }
    set
    {

        // Set value
        _brushobj = value;

        // Notify UI that the value has changed.
        RaisePropertyChanged("BrushObj");
        // OnPropertyChanged("BrushObj"); // Use the appropriate function to notify the UI.
    }
}
```

Then simply set the value with something like this:

```
BrushObj = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("Green");
```

Last you bind it to your View like you did in your question:

```
Background="{Binding BrushObj}"
```

Edit: I tried to make a project myself just to verify that this was indeed working and the following code worked fine. If it's still not working it's more likely to be something with your MVVM setup causing problem.

**MainWindowViewModel:**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
        public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
        {
           private Brush _brushobj = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("Red");
           public Brush BrushObj
           {
                get
                {
                     return _brushobj;
                }
                set
                {
                     _brushobj = value; // Set value
                     RaisePropertyChanged("BrushObj"); // Notify UI that the value has changed.
                }
           }
      }
}
```

**MainWindow:**

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,1"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        FontFamily="Arial"
                        FontSize="16"
                        Text="Testing a lot of stuff here! important stuff!"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                        Background="{Binding BrushObj}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same. But its still not working. Background color haven't changed yet.

Comment: Make sure that you have `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented properly in your ViewModel if it isn't updating. You could also try to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your XAML code. `Background="{Binding BrushObj, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: should I have to uncomment //OnPropertyChanged("BrushObj") event?

Comment: It depends on how you implement INotifyPropertyChanged. If the first code compiled without problems it should be fine, depends on what framework and such you use for MVVM; like for example PRISM or MVVM Light.

Comment: If you are having problems, feel free to post some additional code from your ViewModel and I'll take a look. :)

Comment: in my view I wrote <TextBlock Margin="0,1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Arial"
                    FontSize="16"
                    Text="{Binding Line}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Background="{Binding BrushObj, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
Then, in viewmodel I declared private and public property same as above. and in its constructor I declared BrushObj = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("Green"); 
but still no color in output. :(
I will show you code if you want.

Comment: How do you define your ViewModel? Mine looks like this `public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject`. Also, do you have any other bindings that does work?

Comment: mine is : [Export(typeof(CallControlViewModel))]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    public class CallControlViewModel : ViewModelBase
yes. my other data bindings with textblocks and labels are working properly.

Comment: Make sure that you spelled the name correctly, as I changed it in my example from ´brushobj´ to ´BrushObj`.

Comment: Hi Fuji, I ensured that also. but no use. Should I have to use <setter> property for that?? and how to use it?

Comment: hey I am inheriting ViewModelBase and not ObservableObject. beacause some of my data is bound to ViewModelBase.. 
can that be the problem???

Comment: @deathrace.dj That is fine. You ViewModelBase will inherite something similar to my ObservableObject. You could try to assign the value directly like I have done in my working example, instead of in the constructor to see if that makes any difference. If possible, post more code in your question.

Comment: I read that and couldn't find anything, but you could always try changing `{Binding BrushObj}` to `{Binding DataContext.BrushObj}`.